# How to solve the derivation?

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic

[image: giclab]

Derive the following without assumptions:

¬∃xFx↔∀x¬Fx

How do I solve this derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a proof using Klement's proof checker and the rules described in *forall x*. You may need to use something different with the software you are using, but this may give you an idea how to proceed.

[image]

"CQ" refers to the change of quantifiers rule. A derivation of the CQ rule is given in *forall x* (see link below) on pages 260-1.

Each conditional is derived separately. The biconditional introduction (line 5) is permitted by these rules when I reference both of the conditionals on lines 1-2 and lines 3-4.

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/